# CSS gradient background not stretching when card gets big(React Bootstrap)

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]

Gradient gets cut off when the card gets too big.
What changes need to be made?
The carpenter module gets bigger and the gradient gets cut off at the bottom when scroll bar is involved.
Other components dont cause the problem as their size doesnt involve scrolling. they are smaller in size.

```
.gradient-custom {
  
 /* fallback for old browsers */
 background-image: #6a11cb;

 /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(106, 17, 203, 1), rgba(37, 117, 252, 1));

 /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(106, 17, 203, 1), rgba(37, 117, 252, 1));
  

  
  }
```

```
 <div className='gradient-custom'>
      <div className="container vh-100 me-5 mb-auto">
        <div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100 ">
          <div className="col-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-7">
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
              <div className="card shadow-2-strong card-registration" style={{ width: "80%", height: "100%", borderRadius: "15px" }}>
                <div className="card-body p-4 p-md-5">
                  <div className="text-center mb-4 pb-2 pb-md-0 mb-md-3">
                    <h3>Registration Form</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="formType" className="form-label">Select registration type:</label>
                    <select id="formType" className="form-select form-select-lg" value={formType} onChange={handleSelect}>
                      <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
                      <option value="seller">Seller</option>
                      <option value="customer">Customer</option>
                      <option value="carpenter">Carpenter</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  {formType === "seller" && <Seller />}
                  {formType === "customer" && <Customer />}
                  {formType === "carpenter" && <Carpenter />}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put just enough code into your question to demonstrate the problem. We cannot tell from the image what elements are involved and what is getting cut off as we have no idea what you are applying the linear-gradient to.

Comment: I have updated the React code

Comment: What other styles has .gradient-custom element?

Comment: nothing just this